# Retrieve the most recent records in dynamodb with golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to retrieve the most recent record inserted in my DynamoDB table, the table structure is like this:

- Date (Order Key)
- Id (Partition Key)
- Value

The date value is unix timestamp, this is an example json data:

```
{
  "Date": 1590312898,
  "Id": "87a6614b-1d05-44af-ab4b-6bc0957796b3",
  "Value": 36
}
```

I try to do with ScanInput function with Limit result set to 1 but I can't get the right order and so I got the wrong row. I try with this code:

```
    filt := expression.Name("Date").NotEqual(expression.Value(nil))

    proj := expression.NamesList(expression.Name("Date"), expression.Name("Id"), expression.Name("Value"))

    expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithFilter(filt).WithProjection(proj).Build()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got error building expression:")
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    // Build the query input parameters
    params := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
        Limit:                     aws.Int64(1),
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
        ProjectionExpression:      expr.Projection(),
        TableName:                 aws.String(tableName),
    }

    // Make the DynamoDB Query API call
    result, err := svc.Scan(params)
```

maybe I've to use ScanIndexForward parameters but I don't understand how to set it in the right way.

Any suggestion? It's the right way to proceed?

Thanks in advance

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

I must use QueryInput instead of ScanInput function to use ScanInputForward, this is the new code:

```
      var queryInput = &dynamodb.QueryInput{
            TableName: aws.String(tableName),
            KeyConditions: map[string]*dynamodb.Condition{
                "Type": {
                    ComparisonOperator: aws.String("EQ"),
                    AttributeValueList: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                        {
                            S: aws.String("SM"),
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            ScanIndexForward: aws.Bool(false),
            Limit:            aws.Int64(1),
        }

        result, err := svc.Query(queryInput)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly as your date is the partition key, whenever you do a scan DynamoDB in the backend will be calling each of the partitions individually. Whichever order they're returned in will be the order in the response.

If you want to retrieve this using the [ScanIndexForward](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#API_Query_RequestSyntax), then you would be looking at the sort (or range key)

> Specifies the order for index traversal: If true (default), the traversal is performed in ascending order; if false, the traversal is performed in descending order.
>
> Items with the same partition key value are stored in sorted order by sort key. If the sort key data type is Number, the results are stored in numeric order. For type String, the results are stored in order of UTF-8 bytes. For type Binary, DynamoDB treats each byte of the binary data as unsigned.

I would suggest looking at how you could rearchitect your DynamoDB table to use a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) that would use a partition key that all items use, and a sort key of the date. You could then query this using  ScanIndexForward and retrieve your maximum value.

Otherwise you'll be stuck with performing a scan and then doing post processing to order.

Comment: thank for your reply, I changed the table stucture adding a order key and changin the primary key field as you can see in the main question but it still doesn't work (i have same issue). Moreover i would not to use Global Secondary Index because i want to make a "free" fee service and for use GSI i've to pay monthly.

Comment: Hi, the partition key would need to be the same value for all to use the sort key how you want

Comment: Thank you @mokugo-devops, giving same value to partition key value works. However I've to do queryInput instead of scan to use ScanIndexForward in my code. I'll update my question with solution code.